# Linq DataContext.Mapping.GetTables() returns nothing

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to use LINQ as much as possible so I would like to figure this one out.  I am able to get a list of tables in a user-selected server/database using the DataContext ExecuteQuery method but not using the Mapping.GetTables() enumerator.

Here is what I have (called by a BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(args)):

```
//Build the connection string (args contains the Server and database names)
Dictionary<string, string> args = (Dictionary<string, string>)e.Argument;
string ConnectString = "Data Source=" + args["SqlServerHolder"] + ";Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=" + args["SqlServerDatabaseHolder"];

//Get the connection and pull the list
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectString))
{
    // Open connection
    con.Open();

    //create a linq connection and get the list of database names
    DataContext dc = new DataContext(con);

    //THIS WORKS
    e.Result = new ObservableCollection<string>(dc.ExecuteQuery<string>("SELECT [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='U'").AsEnumerable());

    //THIS COMES BACK EMPTY (tables)
    IEnumerable<string> tables = (from mt in dc.Mapping.GetTables() select mt.TableName);
    e.Result = new ObservableCollection<string>(tables);
}
```

Running the hard coded query works but I would rather use the GetTables() method to avoid that.  The only thing I can think of is the database is connected to on the fly like that and I somehow have to populate the Mapping?

Thanks
Ernie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq-to-sql requires some code to handle the ORM functionality - it works with strongly typed classes.

Now you pick a random database to there are no mappings available hence no result. In other words, there is not DBML for a random database..

The other statement is just plain SQL so it can work in any random database but it does return anything stronly typed.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  So I suppose in situations like this the best/only way is to use hard-coded queries strings?  Does the DataContent object really provide any benefit over traditional ADO objects?

Comment: I think in your case the benefit is minimal.